# jquery get value from input when get value from slider

Tags: jquery

I have a input text

```
<span id="slider-result-dist"></span>
<div class="slider_dist slider"></div> 
    <input type="text" name="filter_dist_sea" id="dist-sea" value="<?php echo $states['filter_dist_sea'] ?>" />
</div>
```

I have create a slider

```
$( ".slider_dist" ).slider({
        animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: 100,
            min: 1,
            max: 1000,
    step: 100,
            slide: function(event, ui) { 
            $( "#slider-result-dist" ).html( ui.value+' Mt' );
    $('#jea-search-dist-sea<?php echo $uid ?>').attr('value', ui.value);
            }
    });
     });
```

I need to use the function change like this, but does not work

```
$('#dist-sea').change(function() {
  alert('change');
});
```

I know the good way is this :

```
$( ".slider_dist" ).slider({

            slide: function(event, ui) { 
            alert(ui.value);
            }
    });
```

It' s possible get the value from input when change from slider ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$( ".YourUI_slider" ).bind( "slidestop", function(event, ui) 
{
    //Do What ever your want      
});
```

**Edit**

```
$("#YourInput").blur(function()
{
   //To get Slider Min value
   var SliderMin=$(".YourUI_slider").slider("values")[0];

   //To get Slider Max value
   var SliderMax=$(".YourUI_slider").slider("values")[1];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i need the event from input text. If the input text change get value....